# Setting timestamp in first empty cell of column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have not been able to find this anywhere. I'm guessing I'm searching for the wrong keywords. So far I have been able to use:

```
    function getFirst() {
    var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var column = spr.getRange('F2:F260');
    var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
    var ct = 0;
    while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
    }
     return (ct);
    }
```

But I can't quite figure out how to set the return value to (new Date()). 
This:

```
    function clockOut() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setValue(getFirst(new Date));
    }
```

Sets the time based off of the ct which, because it's zero, looks like: | 12/31/1899 0:00:00 |. Also in the F2 spot not in the ct spot. I think I'm close yet feel like I'm going in the wrong direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not too far in the first part... after that it becomes a bit confuse... here is a working example, I changed it to allow for easy customization on choosing the column.

```
function clockOut() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var col = "F";// choose the column you want
  sh.getRange(col+getFirstEmptyCell(col)).setValue(new Date());
}

function getFirstEmptyCell(col) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sh.getRange(col+"1:"+col).getValues()
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  ct++;// because we want to get the row after the last non-empty row
  Logger.log(ct);// just to check
  return (ct);
}
```

Comment: Great! Works a charm. Thanks